# Nginx with module for CentOS/RHEL7

Tags: nginx

I'm very new to Nginx, somewhat I figured out using Nginx I can load balance udp based traffic with stream module. I've already installed Nginx and stream is not supported in installed version.

Question 
1. How can I install Nginx with stream or modules to support udp load balance.
2. Stream configuration, should be appended at the end of the configuration file or should be define in separate file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of NGINX is provided by CentOS/RHEL, it might be too old. It is recommended to install NGINX from the [official NGINX repo](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#mainline). This blog has details on [configuring UDP load balancing](https://www.nginx.com/blog/announcing-udp-load-balancing/).

Comment: nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.10.2, I'm using 1.10.2 version. I'm unable to figure out, in which location I should describe below code ? In nginx default.d or conf.d or a as separate file in conf.d/                                                          # Load balance UDP-based DNS traffic across two servers

stream {
    upstream dns_upstreams {
      server 192.168.136.130:53;
      server 192.168.136.131:53;
    }
    server {
      listen 53 udp;
      proxy_pass dns_upstreams;
      proxy_timeout 1s;
      proxy_responses 1;
      error_log logs/dns.log;
    }
}

Comment: You can't put UDP load balancing config in the conf.d because its includes conf.d/* in an `http {}` block. Try putting your code directly in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf